# How to protect client from seeing the request he is sending?

Tags: http, security, https, charles-proxy

I want to encrypt the data inside the HTTP POST request so that the client himself cant see the format of request he is sending to the server via softwares like Charles.

I have implemented HTTPS but when I used Charles I can see whole request I am sending and the response I am receiving. So I thought to encrypt the POST request data.

Q1 Is it good practice to encrypt data of POST request?
Q2 Is there any other way to achieve this ie client cant see his request?

Comment: The client *is creating* the request, yoy can't hide it from the client. What you want is not possible.

Comment: Oh if this is true then in Whatsapp why cant I see a single thing even using any softwares?

Comment: Whatsapp uses websockets, not plain http requests. But you can still sniff and have a look at what's going on, with slightly different tools.

Comment: What tools can I use? and how can you protect web sockets? And according to my understanding web sockets are also some HTTP requests